# How to join multiple observables in rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

How to join multiple different observables and subscribe from viewmodel?

I am using single source of truth
principle, so firstly I get data from db then load data from webservice and finally save all data to the db.

For that I used rxjava, room, dagger2, retrofit libraries. But there was a some problem. I must to get
multiple list from webservice and save each list to database. I try some solution, but this code
replies the same request multiple times. Progressbar changes each time. How can I simplify? Best practices for that.

Api.json

```
{
"data": {
        "ad": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "image": "ad/ru/msG0y8vuXl.png"
            }
            ...
        ],
        "categories": [...],
        "status":     [...],
        "location":   [...]
        }
}
```

HomeRepository.kt

```
class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val indexApi: IndexApi, 
    private val categoryDao: CategoryDao, 
    private val userDao: UserDao, 
    private val adDao: AdDao
) {

    fun getCategoryList(): Observable<List<Category>> {
        val categoryListDb: Observable<List<Category>> = categoryDao.getCategoryList()
            .filter { t: List<Category> -> t.isNotEmpty() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .toObservable()

        val categoryListApi: Observable<List<Category>> = indexApi.getIndex()
            .toObservable()
            .map { response ->
                Observable.create { subscriber: ObservableEmitter<Any> ->
                    categoryDao.insertCategoryList(response.data.categories)
                    subscriber.onComplete()
                }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .subscribe()
                response.data.categories
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

        return Observable
            .concatArrayEager(categoryListDb, categoryListApi)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    fun getUserList(): Observable<List<User>> {
        // same as above
    }

    fun getAdList(): Observable<List<Ad>> {
        // same as above
    }
}
```

HomeViewmodel.kt

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val homeRepository: HomeRepository
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val categoryLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Category>>> = MutableLiveData()
    private val adLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Ad>>> = MutableLiveData()
    private val userLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<List<User>>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun categoryResponse(): LiveData<Resource<List<Category>>> = categoryLiveData
    fun adResponse(): LiveData<Resource<List<Ad>>> = adLiveData
    fun userResponse(): LiveData<Resource<List<User>>> = userLiveData

    fun loadCategory() {
        categoryLiveData.postValue(Resource.loading())
        compositeDisposable.add(
            homeRepository.getCategoryList()
                .subscribe({ response ->
                    categoryLiveData.postValue(Resource.succeed(response))
                }, { error ->
                    categoryLiveData.postValue(Resource.error(error))
                })
        )
    }
    fun loadAd() { // Same as above }
    fun loadUser() { // Same as above }
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
fun init(){
    // ..
    viewmodel.loadCategory()
    viewmodel.adResponse()
    viewmodel.userResponse()

    viewmodel.categoryResponse().observe(this, Observer {
        when(it.status){
        Status.SUCCEED -> { progressBar.toGone() }
        Status.LOADING -> { progressBar.toVisible() }
        Status.FAILED  -> { progressBar.toGone() }
        }
    }
    viewmodel.adResponse().observe(this, Observer { //Same as above }
    viewmodel.userResponse().observe(this, Observer { //Same as above }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prevent multiple calls from happening in your code, by wrapping `indexApi.getIndex().toObservable()` inside a connectable observable.

This a bit more of an advanced topic, but roughly what you need to do is:

Create a field in your class `HomeRepository`:

```
private val observable = Observable.defer {
  indexApi.getIndex().toObservable()
}.replay(1).refCount()
```

And then, you need to replace every use of `indexApi.getIndex().toObservable()` with `observable`.

This might not exactly achieve the result you expected. This blog post seems to be a write-up of other possible options: https://blog.danlew.net/2016/06/13/multicasting-in-rxjava/